# How to apply multiple functions to a dataframe in R

Tags: r

I am working with a relatively large dataset with a lot of attributes, is there any simple way(no extra packages) to let the output be like this row names as attributes name and col names as the function:

```
               Min   Max                       
Sepal.Length   4.3   7.9
Sepal.Width    2.0   4.4
Petal.Length   1.0   6.9
Petal.Width    0.1   2.5
```

Currently, when I `sapply` multiple functions to the data, the output is this

```
     Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
min      4.300000    2.000000        1.000    0.100000
max      7.900000    4.400000        6.900    2.500000
mean     5.843333    3.057333        3.758    1.199333
```

However, this output will be too wide to fit in a pdf when knitting when dealing with large number of attributes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the t function

```
transposed_table <- t(normal_table)
```